# Regexp_extract return data 2 times (duplicate) in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I'd like to ask about a problem related to regexp_extract in Hive. So, I'd like extract a value from json object

```
{"data":[{"key":"text","value":"12345"},{"key2":"text2","value":""}],"key3":time1,"key4":time2}
```

I use the regexp_extract query like this:

```
max(if(index=0, regexp_extract(column1, '"key":"text","value":"(.+?)"', 1), '')) as extract1,
max(if(index=1, regexp_extract(column1, '"key":"text","value":"(.+?)"', 1), '')) as extract2
```

but I got duplicate data for each, so let say it should return only 2 rows (row 1, row 2) but it gave me 4 rows instead (row 1, row 1, row 2, row 2) with completely identical data.

However, I've solved this by changing the regexp_extract into get_json_object like this:

```
max(if(index = 0, get_json_object(column1, '$.data[0].value'), '')) as extract_1,
max(if(index = 1, get_json_object(column1, '$.data[0].value'), '')) as extract_2
```

but still couldn't find the reason. Does anyone know why? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: why don't you explode the JSON object?

Comment: @zealous Hi zealous! Thanks for your response, yep I've read more or less about JSON object, but still got confused.. By the way, this is not always the case though. Before, the regexp_extract works fine for me, and this was the first time this problem occurred. So, I'm just wondering whether I missed something....

Comment: regexp_extract does not generate rows. check your data and provide minimal reproducible example please